# Changing color of label based on text it holds

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel

I'm trying to change the color of a UILabel depending on the `.text` value it's holding.

I've come up with this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
titel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", titelJSON];

    if (titel.text == @"PROBLEEM") {
        titel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        NSLog(@"1: %@", titel.textColor);
    } else if (titel.text == @"WAARSCHUWING") {
        titel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        NSLog(@"2: %@", titel.textColor);
    } else {
        titel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        NSLog(@"3: %@", titel.textColor);
    }
```

Any thoughts?

I have logs in there to see what the `if` statement is actually picking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot compare strings using == in objective-c. You should use the `isEqualToString` message instead. Like [titel.text isEqualToString:@"PROBLEEM"]